# How to make an image replace a JButton when clicked

Tags: java

Currently trying to make a TicTacToe game, i have the frame and 9 buttons set up (for each square the players can choose). I'm having a bit of trouble adding functions to each button when clicked.

```
package OX;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class OX{

public static void main(String[] args){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("OX");
    frame.setSize(800,800);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    frame.add(panel);
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    JButton button1 = new JButton("1");
    button1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,100));
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 1;
    c.insets = new Insets(50,50,50,50);     
    panel.add(button1, c);
    JButton button2 = new JButton("2");
    button2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,100));
    c.gridx = 2;
    c.gridy = 1;
    panel.add(button2, c);
    JButton button3 = new JButton("3");
    button3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,100));
    c.gridx = 3;
    c.gridy = 1;
    panel.add(button3, c);
    JButton button4 = new JButton("4");
    button4.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,100));
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 2;
    panel.add(button4, c);
    JButton button5 = new JButton("5");
    button5.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,100));
    c.gridx = 2;
    c.gridy = 2;
    panel.add(button5, c);
    JButton button6 = new JButton("6");
    button6.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,100));
    c.gridx = 3;
    c.gridy = 2;
    panel.add(button6, c);
    JButton button7 = new JButton("7");
    button7.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,100));
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 3;
    panel.add(button7, c);
    JButton button8 = new JButton("8");
    button8.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,100));
    c.gridx = 2;
    c.gridy = 3;
    panel.add(button8, c);
    JButton button9 = new JButton("9");
    button9.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,100));
    c.gridx = 3;
    c.gridy = 3;
    panel.add(button9, c);      
  }
}
```

I've tried lots of different ideas but just cant seem to get it right.

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First your code is not modular. I would suggest you modularize it with the proper classes

Important accept of Swing is the listener class. To write the functions of the buttons; you need to implement ActionListener and build this class
All the game logic is going to be implemented in this Listener class.

Have a separate method to verify the game status(who wins/loses) from this listener. This should make you task simple.

Please Refer - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html
http://www.codejava.net/java-core/the-java-language/java-8-lambda-listener-example

Hope this helps. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for the reply, i've implemented ActionListener and all seems well, however, i have created a bug and i have no idea how or why it occurs when i launch the program. Everytime i launch the program it randomly chooses which buttons are placed on the panel. Could this be due to all of them being ran at once and it chooses a random order to place the buttons?

Comment: sorry, can't comment on it without seeing the code. Please post the code

Comment: I had to create a new comment on this post above to fit the entire thing in

Comment: Scrap my previous comments! I've solved the issue of the buttons being randomly "selected". Thank you for your time and help, it was very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

```
package OX;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class OX{

public static void main(String[] args){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("OX");
    frame.setSize(800,800);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    frame.add(panel);
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();        
    JButton button1 = new JButton("1");
    button1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,100));
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 1;
    c.insets = new Insets(50,50,50,50);
    button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            System.out.println("test");
            }
        });
    panel.add(button1, c);      
    JButton button2 = new JButton("2");
    button2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,100));
    c.gridx = 2;
    c.gridy = 1;
    button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            System.out.println("test2");
            }
        });
    panel.add(button2, c);      
    JButton button3 = new JButton("3");
    button3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,100));
    c.gridx = 3;
    c.gridy = 1;
    button3.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            System.out.println("test3");
            }
        });
    panel.add(button3, c);      
    JButton button4 = new JButton("4");
    button4.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,100));
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 2;
    button4.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            System.out.println("test4");
            }
        });
    panel.add(button4, c);      
    JButton button5 = new JButton("5");
    button5.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,100));
    c.gridx = 2;
    c.gridy = 2;
    button5.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            System.out.println("test5");
            }
        });
    panel.add(button5, c);      
    JButton button6 = new JButton("6");
    button6.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,100));
    c.gridx = 3;
    c.gridy = 2;
    button6.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            System.out.println("test6");
            }
        });
    panel.add(button6, c);      
    JButton button7 = new JButton("7");
    button7.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,100));
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 3;
    button7.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            System.out.println("test7");
            }
        });
    panel.add(button7, c);
    JButton button8 = new JButton("8");
    button8.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,100));
    c.gridx = 2;
    c.gridy = 3;
    panel.add(button8, c);
    button8.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            System.out.println("test8");
            }
        });     
    JButton button9 = new JButton("9");
    button9.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,100));
    c.gridx = 3;
    c.gridy = 3;
    panel.add(button9, c);      
    button9.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            System.out.println("test9");
            }
        });

    }
}
```

@Vijayan Kani

I added the ActionListener to each button